# Is there a way to implement a full Python (psychopy) procedure into neurobs Presentation without rewriting the whole code?

Tags: python, psychopy, presentation, code-translation

I found an option to get python to play Presentation procedures, but not the other way around. I have a ton of code and rewriting it into a different language would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such conversion tool available at the moment.

However, it is in principle possible to make it. PsychoPy Builder saves experiments in the open .psyexp format and then that is converted to Python code. Someone could write converters to other script structures and languages, for example, NeuroBS Presentation, PsychToolbox, etc.